# passive form or active form?

Tags: passive-voice

In technical writing, when writing  general things that what others have done for e.g. in the *introduction section*

for example, if i want to write;

> 1. The knowledge based object recognition nowadays *has gained* increased
>      interest in point processing tasks.

can we write as above? But I feel, it is not meaningful as the verb should be *has been gained* as the doer is the writer or reader..

or should we obey passive form like;

> 1. The knowledge based object recognition nowadays *is gained* increased
>      interest in point processing tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the first option:

> The knowledge based object recognition nowadays has gained increased interest in point processing tasks.

Using "is gained" is not correct in this context.